# How to assign classes to properties of "new () =>" type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dependency-injection, typeof

There is a hierarchy

```
class Thing { }

class BarView<Type> extends React.Component<{ obj: Type }, {}> { }

class FlossView extends BarView<Thing> {  }

class Foo<Type> {
    renderer?: new () => BarView<Type>

    constructor(view?: new () => BarView<Type>) {
         this.renderer = view
    }
}
```

Why can I call the constructor of `Foo` with class name signature and not have any error like this

```
let foo = new Foo<Thing>(FlossView)
```

... while the following code produces an error?

```
let foo = new Foo<Thing>()
foo.renderer = FlossView
/* [ts]
Type 'typeof FlossView' is not assignable to type 'BarView<Thing> | undefined'.
Type 'typeof FlossView' is not assignable to type 'BarView<Thing>'.*/
```

How do I get the not `typeof FlossView` version of the class, but just `FlossView`?

Comment: Real code differs from the one you've posted. This one works as expected, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BarView%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20render()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FlossView%20extends%20BarView%20%7B%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20renderer%3F%3A%20new%20()%20%3D%3E%20BarView%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(view%3F%3A%20new%20()%20%3D%3E%20BarView)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.renderer%20%3D%20view%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%0D%0Afoo.renderer%20%3D%20FlossView

Comment: There is no `view` property, although the error implies that there's one. In order to get this error, it has to be `constructor(public view?: FlossView)`, not `constructor(view?: new () => BarView)`.

Comment: @estus, reading your comments, not explicitly getting anywhere. Will attempt to fiddle around with declarations...

Comment: @estus Oh, gosh darn, there is an enormous typo in the question!

Comment: Of course, we have to apply FlossView to `foo.renderer`

Comment: Even then this doesn't explain how you can get this error. Check again your original code, please. There should be `renderer?: FlossView` somewhere because that's the only way to get `is not assignable to type 'FlossView | undefined`.

Comment: @estus well there is obviously, except no `renderer?: FlossView` but `renderer?: new () => FlossView`

Comment: @estus, truth be told, generics are actually involved. I'll update the question.

Comment: @estus, I have updated the question

Comment: @estus I have posted the answer.

Comment: @estus I have updated the answer, issue solved.

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case closed. The signature is invalid, the most-base class `React.Component` has never ever had a constructor of type `new () => React.Component`.

Figures, there is only a constructor with one parameter, `props`.
And thus the type declaration of `renderer` property is invalid. It should be

```
renderer?: new (props) => BarView<Type>
```